# Angular app is not deploying after tests pass in Travis CI

Tags: angular, heroku, travis-ci

I am writing a new application in Angular and I it does not deploy after the tests pass. I don't know what to do to make it 'go'.

Here is the travis:

```
language: node_js
node_js: node
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: wRqEQR8YsVtESb1T18
  app: enigmatic-falls-02464
  on:
    repo: lightsage88/showYourMoves 
  skip_cleanup: 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after some Google-fu, I found this link:

```
https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-deploy-your-angular-9-app-to-heroku-in-minutes-51d171c2f0d
```

1. I installed express via:

```
npm i express
```

2. I created a file in the root directory which I called 'app.js'
3. I entered the following code in the 'app.js' file I created:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.use(express.static('./dist/<THE NAME OF THE APP IN PACKAGE.JSON>'))

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'dist/<THE NAME OF THE APP IN PACKAGE.JSON>/'})
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080)
```

4. Then I went into 'package.json' and set the build option to:

```
"ng build --prod"
```

After that, all my problems were fixed.
Tl;dr:

I added Express to my application, created a file that serves up the the file that initiates the app. For whatever reason, 'ng serve' wouldn't work on Travis CI after the tests passed.

You can see my bare-bones, still technically in progress app, at:
https://enigmatic-falls-02464.herokuapp.com/